# Getting PDF from imported Histogram

Tags: probability-or-statistics, import, random, histograms

So I'd like to create a probability density function from an existing histogram from a program that I use. My input data is of the form

```
bin    hits
0.     0
0.025  0
0.05   0
0.075 15
0.1   97

etc.
```

and I imported it into Mathematica the following way

```
data

{{0.,0},{0.025,0},{0.05,0},{0.075,15},{0.1,97},...}
```

I want to read this data and create a probability density from it. The end goal is to then `RandomVariate` around this `pdf`:

```
pdf = HistogramDistribution[data, {bins[[1]], bins[[-1]], bwidth}]
new_data = RandomVariate[pdf,n]
```

My first attempt was to use `HistogramDistribution` to create a `PDF` from the imported `Histogram` - since this requires a set of data points, I attempted the following:

```
For[j = 1, j < Length[data] + 1, j++,
 For[k = 0, k < data[[j]][[2]], k++,
  AppendTo[temphisto, data[[j]][[1]]]
 ]
];

pdf = HistogramDistribution[temphisto, {bins[[1]], bins[[-1]], bwidth}];
```

Of course, this gets unnecessarily time consuming once I crank up the initial histogram entries and it also feels redundant to do so since I can achieve the output of `HistogramList` right from the start:

```
HistogramList[temphisto, {bins[[1]], bins[[-1]], bwidth}]

{{0.,0.025,0.05,0.075,0.1,...},
 {0,0,0,15,97,...}}
```

Is there a way to turn the output from `HistogramList` to a `HistogramDistribution` or maybe create a probability density function from an imported histogram?

Thanks for the aid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`WeightedData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WeightedData.html) using the second column as weights vector:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = Transpose[{Range[0, 1, .05], RandomInteger[50, 21]}];
data // TableForm // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{cc}
>  0. & 20 \\
>  0.05 & 1 \\
>  0.1 & 48 \\
>  0.15 & 2 \\
>  0.2 & 6 \\
>  0.25 & 3 \\
>  0.3 & 16 \\
>  0.35 & 28 \\
>  0.4 & 33 \\
>  0.45 & 31 \\
>  0.5 & 33 \\
>  0.55 & 17 \\
>  0.6 & 12 \\
>  0.65 & 44 \\
>  0.7 & 40 \\
>  0.75 & 30 \\
>  0.8 & 24 \\
>  0.85 & 2 \\
>  0.9 & 25 \\
>  0.95 & 11 \\
>  1. & 21 \\
> \end{array}$

```
{bins, counts} = Transpose[data];
wd = WeightedData[bins, counts];
dist = HistogramDistribution[wd]
```

> DataDistribution[<>,{21}]

```
SeedRandom[1]
RandomVariate[dist, 5]
```

> {0.532869, 0.271123, 0.615577, 0.198003, 0.350237}

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I tried this and it works fine! It took me some time to figure out how to set the range in HistogramDistribution correctly, but I got it to work.

Comment: @user46208, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. Welcome to mma.se.